# Checking availability of users connected to my PHP/JSP server

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets, applet

I'm developing a web application that will be accessed by many users on an intranet. At almost every time I would like the server to know the clients that have logged unto the system. The idea that I have currently is that of pinging machines (clients) that the users are sitting on. Every time the user logs in, I would like some code to capture the IP address for the user's machine and send it to the server. The code I have is using json which is however limiting because I will not always have internet access on the intranet to access 'http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?'. Is there someone with alternative ideas that can help? I would really like to get the IP addresses for users as they log in.

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone going through the problem I posted above they may find my solution helpful.
I have devised an algorithm yet to be implemented. The algorithm gets each user's IP via the simple $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] using php and using using some JSP to constantly ping the user from the server to check the user's connection status. To ensure absolute availability for the user the client also uses JS to determine user activity on the application and sends some infor to the server via Ajax if the user is inactive for a given number of minutes. I really think this will work especially that it has worked on my paper work. I will share my experience when I finally implement my thinking.